# exclusive lock mysql

Tags: mysql, locking, phpmyadmin

I want to generate the next `enroll_no`.  It is incremented by group for each `institute_id` and every new institute has to start `enroll_no` at 1. When an institute has multiple branches then the problem happens.

If we fetch `MAX(enroll_no)` and then increment 1 and insert and at the same time branch 2 fetches the same `MAX(enroll_no)`, then after incrementing they both send same enroll_no to the server.  This creates a duplicate enroll_no for the institute_id.

I need them to be exclusive and possibly use a lock there but i don't know how to go about that.

[image: stu enrollment table]

Answer (score 0):

I'm making assumptions here based on the available data.  I do not know your table name so I'm going to assume it's called `institute_enroll_table` for now.  I also called your insert variables by fake names `myid` and `my_instutute_id` since I don't know what your current insert looks like.

The easiest way to fix this is going to be to do the MAX(enroll_no) in your INSERT query rather than do it as a separate query.  The second INSERT will wait on the first and therefore will get a different MAX.  The COALESCE makes the value 1 when there is no record found.

```
INSERT INTO institute_enroll_table(id, institute_id, enroll_no)
SELECT myid, my_institute_id, 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT MAX(enroll_no)+1 FROM institute_enroll_table ie WHERE 
ie.institute_id=my_institute_id)
     ,1)AS enroll_no
```